# LiveCD with running ssh server

Tags: live-cd

I am looking for a LiveCD with a running ssh daemon. I need it because i want to connect to an abandoned server and make a backup. The server hasn't a monitor.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

sysrescuecd does have a running ssh daemon, but you would need to [specify the root password in the startup options](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Booting_the_CD-ROM#Network_configuration_and_remote_access) - with the default settings you would end up with an empty password and thus the account would be exempted from remote login.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is almost what i want, but as you said, i have to first manually specify the root password, what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: you might just reconfigure the bootloader to include the rootpasswd=<somepassword> option along with others you might need for the network setup. This is not particulary hard to achieve - take a look at http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Booting_the_CD-ROM#How_to_change_the_default_boot_options for details.

Comment: the option is named rootpass= in current version (6.1.1)

Answer (score 2):

You can [create an Ubuntu LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) with an appropriately configured SSH daemon, users & passwords (or better, SSH keys!), etc. -- This may take a bit of work, but it guarantees that you'll have a LiveCD with all the tools you need to make a backup of the server (via simple tar, dump, dd, or any other  mechanism you can fit onto a CD).

Answer (score 2):

I use the [PLD Rescue CD](http://rescuecd.pld-linux.org/). It's pretty compact, but includes most of the Linux (and some Windows) utilities I need. I think sshd is enabled upon boot, but you'll need to simply assign a password of your choice. The default is "pld".

Comment: I confirm ssh login works on boot without any user interaction. Thanks.

Comment: Looks almost like what I need, but no apparent UEFI support...